# Using dnsjava to resolve a given IP to its Hostnames

Tags: java, dns, ip, pointers, dnsjava

I want to get a list of all registered Domains for a given IP Address .
Could I use PTR records. I tried the following

```
ip = "217.13.68.220";
l = new Lookup(ip, Type.PTR );
l.setResolver(new SimpleResolver("8.8.8.8"));
l.run();
```

This IP should be resolved to zeit.de but the lookup returns:

> host_not_found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an IPV4 address, you need to

1. Reverse the octets
2. Append the in-addr.arpa domain

So, in your case, you should pass "220.68.13.217.in-addr.arpa." to the resolver.